# Screen of an Old App in iPhone X iOS 11 Adjustment

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode9, iphone-x

We updated today to xCode 9 and our Visual Studio for Xamarin Development. 
I tested my apps on iPhone X and it has a spaces on upper and lower portion. Any idea and work around to update the app?

using Visual Studio Xamarin Forms.

[image]

Comment: What is the top-level container of that Form's Page and its attributes?

Comment: It looks as if the iPhone X is running your app in compatibility mode instead of native.

Comment: Hi Sushi, Navigation Page is my Top Level Form's Page.

Comment: Solution : The new iPhone X requires a launch image sized at 1125px × 2436px which is a 3x image for 375pt × 812pt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build against the iOS 11 SDK and have a launch storyboard or your app will run in compatibility mode on iPhone X, like you're seeing.

Enabling native resolution on the iPhone X may cause other issues that you'll need to work through. You should layout your views/constraints to the safe areas to solve those issues.